# Multi-Class Classification: SMOTE oversampling for multiple columns in a row

Tags: python, text-classification, oversampling

I have an imbalanced dataset contained in a dataframe called *city_country* that is made up of 5 columns:

1. Content of a tweet = **preprocessed**
2. An event type (e.g. tweet relates to earthquake = 'earthquake', typhoon = 'typhoon', etc.) = **event_type**
3. Latitude of where the tweet was sent = **lat**
4. Longitude of where the tweet was sent = **long**
5. An event label (e.g. tweet relates to earthquake = 1, typhoon = 2, etc.) = **event_id**

In the dataframe called *city_country*, the class (**event_id**) is imbalanced. Before testing the predictive power of different text classifiers, to predict the **event_id** from the content of a tweet (**preprocessed)**, I want to oversample the minority classes.

It is important that when I duplicate the entries that belong to minority classes that I duplicate all 5 columns.

What I have done so far (incorrectly) is only oversample the tweet content (**preprocessed** and the **event_id**. In the below code, I convert the tweets into vectors (which I do not want to do but to my knowledge, I have to) and then overrepresent minority classes. This only oversamples the vectorised tweet (*x_words*) and the event_id (*y*).

```
tfidf_words = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=0, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english')

x_words = tfidf_words.fit_transform(city_country.preprocessed).toarray()

# new dataframe 'label' that contains the event_id for each preprocessed tweet
y = city_country.event_id

x_train_words, x_test_words, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_words, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Use SMOTE to oversample the minority classes
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=12)
x_train_words_sm, y_train_words_sm = sm.fit_sample(x_train_words, y_train)

# Count the number of occurences in the y_train sets to ensure that the oversampling worked 
from collections import Counter
class_check_woSMOTE = Counter(y_train)
class_check_words = Counter(y_train_words_sm)
```

To my knowledge, the use of *SMOTE* in *imblearn.over_sampling* requires you to feed real values (not strings) and only 2 values - an 'x' and a 'y'. In this case, 'x' is my vectorised training set of tweets and 'y' is my event label.

Is there a way for me to simply split my dataframe into training and test sets, then oversample all 5 columns for the minority classes, so that the output is a larger dataframe that contains all 5 columns? I can then use this to predict the event_id and hopefully perform the equivalent of a vlookup, so that I can join the tweet with its respective *lat* and *long* values.

Answer (score 0):

SMOTE in imblearn.over_sampling can accept a sparse_vector as an input. You could do the oversampling and then split into your test/train sets.

If I understand your question correctly, the following worked for me;

Give the following a try:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import Tfidfvectorizer
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

strings = city_country.preprocessed

def create_vec(strings):

    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'char_wb',ngram_range=(2,3))
    tf.fit(strings)
    X = tf.transform(strings)

    return X

vecs = create_vec(strings)

y = city_country.event_id

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Then you can split based on the ouput